# How to set ACLineStatus using ACPI functions

Tags: c#, winapi, acpi

I want to read the value of BatteryLifePercent and if it is above 80%(0.80) then set ACLineStatus to offline.

I have tried using

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern Boolean GetSystemPowerStatus(out SystemPowerStatus sps);

    private enum ACLineStatus : byte
    {
        Offline = 0,
        Online = 1,
        Unknown = 255
    }

    private enum BatteryFlag : byte
    {
        High = 1,
        Low = 2,
        Critical = 4,
        Charging = 8,
        NoSystemBattery = 128,
        Unknown = 255
    }

    private struct SystemPowerStatus
    {
        public ACLineStatus LineStatus;
        public BatteryFlag flgBattery;
        public Byte BatteryLifePercent;
        public Byte Reserved1;
        public Int32 BatteryLifeTime;
        public Int32 BatteryFullLifeTime;
    }

    public static Boolean ACPowerPluggedIn()
    {
        SystemPowerStatus SPS = new SystemPowerStatus();
        GetSystemPowerStatus(out SPS);

        if (SPS.LineStatus == ACLineStatus.Online)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Int32 BatteryCharge()
    {
        SystemPowerStatus SPS = new SystemPowerStatus();
        GetSystemPowerStatus(out SPS);

        return (Int32)SPS.BatteryLifePercent;
    }
```

It can be used to read BatteryLifePercent. But I dont know how to set ACLineStatus to offline for avoid further charging.

I also want to know, is it possible using acpi control methods([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536139(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))?

Answer (score 0):

ACPI methods can only be called from a kernel driver, and then only
from the driver stack for the device that the method is declared in in the
DSDT.